# Complex binding statement for KnockoutJS with sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable

Are complex bindings not supported when using KnockoutJS with jQuery UI Sortable?

This works:

```
<div class="accordion edit-test" id="edit-questions" 
     data-bind="foreach: currentItem().questions ">
```

But this does not:

```
<div class="accordion edit-test" id="edit-questions" 
     data-bind="sortable:{ data: currentItem().questions }">
```

---

Here's my current workaround:

```
<!-- ko with: currentItem() -->

<div class="accordion edit-test" id="edit-questions" 
     data-bind="sortable:{ data: questions }">
```

Comment: I would be happy to help you out.  Can you demonstrate your issue based on this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rspf6/?  Also, this is assuming that you are using this binding: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Comment: @RPNiemeyer - I'm guessing that binding is what I'm missing.  Does that fix this particular issue, or should it work either way?

Comment: @RPNiemeyer - also, thanks for all the time you spend here helping people with KO.  It's really appreciated!  The framework is unbelievable.  (and I found a decent workaround for this anyway)

Comment: Yes, you would need the binding.  Knockout ignores bindings that it does not know about, so it would, by default, ignore `sortable`.

Comment: Glad that you are enjoying KO!